# Evaluate $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }e^{-n}\cdot \prod_{k=1}^n(1+\frac{1}{k})^k$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Evaluate the following limit:
$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }e^{-n}\cdot \prod_{k=1}^n(1+\frac{1}{k})^k$

I tried to name $y_n=e^{-n}\cdot \prod_{k=1}^n(1+\frac{1}{k})^k$ with $n\geq 0$ and to prove that $y_n$ is a decreasing sequence, bounded between $[0,\frac{2}{e}]$, thus it converges. But I got stuck here.

Can somebody give me a hint to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried logarithms?

Comment: No, I haven't neither tried logarithms, nor do I notice how I should try them. Can you  describe your idea a little bit?

Comment: Taking the logarithm gives $$\sum_{k=1}^n (k\log(1+k^{-1})-1 )= \sum_{k=1}^n (k(k^{-1}-\frac{k^{-2}}{2}+O(k^{-3}))-1)$$ $$=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{-k^{-1}}{2}+O(k^{-2})=-\frac12 \log(k)+O(1)$$

Answer (score 3):

Your product is
$$y_n=e^{-n}\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{(k+1)^k}{k^k}
=e^{-n}\frac{(n+1)^n}{n!}=e^{-n}\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}
\sim \frac{e}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}$$
by Stirling. So $y_n\to0$, and $y_n\sqrt n\to e/\sqrt{2\pi}$.

Comment: I think this approach is actually better than taking logarithms. Very elegant, +1

Comment: Thank you very much! I've never used Stirling's formula before, i must admit it shortens the computation of yn considerably.

Answer (score 0):

Lord Shark the Unknown's answer is more informative and straightforward, but I guess I'll leave this answer here since I suggested taking logarithms in the comments.
Let $a_n = e^{-n}\cdot \prod_{k=1}^n(1+\frac{1}{k})^k$ and notice that $a_n>0$ for all $n$.
We have that

\begin{align}
\log a_n
&=
-n + \sum_{k=1}^nk\log\left(1+\frac1k\right)
\\&\leqslant
-n + \sum_{k=1}^n k\left(\frac1k - \frac1{2k^2}+\frac1{3k^3}\right)
\\&=
-n + \sum_{k=1}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{2k} + \frac1{3k^2}\right)
\\&=
-\frac12\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\right) + \frac13\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^2}\right)
\\&\leqslant
-\frac12 H_n +\frac13\frac{\pi^2}{6},
\end{align}

where $H_n$ is the $n$-th harmonic number and $\pi^2/6$ comes from the famous Basel problem.
Of course, the exact value is not important; it suffices to show that the series $\sum_{k\geqslant 1} \frac1{k^2}$ is convergent.

Because $H_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$, it follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\log a_n = -\infty$, so by continuity we obtain that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0$.

Comment: Thank you a lot! It's always a good thing to see more than just one method of  solving a problem

Comment: Look here https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/u261115h1970650p13659279